# Blender will not start in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, blender

I have just installed Blender in Ubuntu 20.04. When I select Blender to open it, I get the initial Blender screen and then the application disappears. Suggestions will be very welcome.

I ran `blender` in a terminal with the following output:

```
/run/user/1000/snap.blender/gvfs/
non-existent directory found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/
python Warning: property 'release_confirm' not found in keymap item 'OperatorProperties'
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Thank you Nmath, Jos and user 535733. I have tried both approaches; latterly removing the snap version of Blender and using the terminal and sudo apt install blender. Again Blender started  but then vanished; on this occasion I was prompted to submit an error report which I have done. This computer is dual boot and I do use Blender in Windows 10 but I would like to transfer as much as possible to Linux.

Comment: In a terminal screen, enter `blender`. When the app disappears, look for error messages. Add those to your question (by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1242784/edit) it) so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you. /run/user/1000/snap.blender/gvfs/ non-existent directory
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
Warning: property 'release_confirm' not found in keymap item 'OperatorProperties'
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Rename your user preferences file `/home/[username]/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

A crash is a bug, not a user mistake. You didn't do anything wrong.

1. Report the bug to the [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/store):

   - Find the Blender snap's download page in the [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/store)
   - Click on the  "*Report a problem with this snap*" link.
   - If possible, attach the `/tmp/crash.txt` file to the bug report. That file includes vital information that the developer needs to locate and fix the bug.
2. Replace the snap version of Blender with the deb version of Blender.

   - Deb and Snap are two different types of software package. Since one crashed, try the other. This a workaround that gets a version of Blender working on your system. It doesn't fix the original problem.
   - Open a terminal:

     ```
     snap remove blender
     sudo apt install blender
     ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sudo apt install libllvm6.0
```

It helped me